# Использование словарей в скрипте

Tags: python, python-3.6

Требуется создать три словаря

```
name = {} #Имя
age = {} #Возраст
country = {} #Страна
```

В каждый из словарей добавлять message.chat.id(id пользователя), чтобы далее проверять по id хранимые данные в словаре.
В функции собственно пытаюсь сделать что-то наподобии

```
    name[usr_id] = message.text
    age[usr_id] = message.text
    country[usr_id] = message.text
```

и получаю ошибку в лицо

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: "Что-то наподобии" или именно этот код? Приведенный фрагмент кода не выдает никаких ошибок: https://ideone.com/MfhuzV Добавьте в вопрос именно тот код, с которым у вас возникла проблема.

Comment: Очевидно, вместо какого-то словаря вы случайно создали строку и проглядели это.

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись.
Под "что-то наподобии" имел ввиду например
`name = str(message.text)`
и после присвоение:
`name[usr_id] = name`
также вывод делаю обращаясь к ключу, у вас же, в вышеуказанной ссылке, просто обращение. Как корректнее?

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя создавать переменные с одинаковым именем. У вас может быть либо строковая переменная `name`, либо словарь `name`.

Используйте как-то так:

```py
name = str(message.text)
nameDict = Dict()
nameDict[uid] = name
```

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы переопределяете name, как строку

```
name = str(...)
```

и после этого пытаетесь индексировать ее, о чем и говорит ошибка.

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

В вольном переводе:

> ОшибкаТипа: объект 'str' (строка) не поддерживает присвоение элементов

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное! Внимательность - наше все. Здоровья вам!

Comment: Лучшее спасибо - галочка под ответом :)